# Issue with write a file from Base64 content document (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: luatex

I want to store a binary file (pdf) in a document.
To do this, I encode it in base64 (utf-8) and save it as an external file.
My example doesn't work.
If you use a text file instead of a pdf, you can see that extra lines appear when decoding.
Encoded with this - https://base64.guru/converter/encode/text .
How to fix it?

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
%=========================
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\setminted{xleftmargin=0.5cm, linenos, numbersep=5pt, breaklines, frame=single, framesep=1ex,  fontsize=\small}
\directlua{%
io.output("base64.tex","w +");
io.write((mime.unb64("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")));}
\begin{document}
%   \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{base64.pdf}
\inputminted{TEX}{base64.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the base 64 block has windows ^M^J line ends exept the last line and has cyrillic comments `% пакет для вывода листингов` not shown in your image?

Comment: Your base64 text string contains `\r\n` sequences when decoded, this is a Windows-style line ending that may be displayed as two newlines in other systems. I think that is a separate issue from the pdf inclusion, as it seems to be a setting of the conversion website that you have used.

Comment: you probably need `wb` not `w` mode so it does not mess with line ends

Comment: It works for a text file if you encode it here: https://appdevtools.com/base64-encoder-decoder . But I need to store a pdf. Encoding in Windows can be done like this: certutil -encodehex -f MTUCIfig.pdf base64.pdf 0x40000001 . There is the same problem with extra lines. Thanks for the help @David Carlisle

Comment: I found the documentation, but I'm doing something wrong. There is about what you said. https://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/mime.html#unb64  
The example doesn't work. Thanks for the help @Marijn

Comment: did you add the b flag to the Lua write as suggested? (the issue is with the file write not the base64 encoding)

Comment: would base64 encode in Lua not using a web tool eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618946/lua-base64-encode

Comment: Yes. I tried. It has no effect. @David Carlisle

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle

Comment: It doesn't work that way either: certutil -encodehex -f test.txt enc.txt 0x80000001 -  Use \n line terminators instead of \r\n @Marijn

Comment: The issue is with base64 encoding. The first line works "U3RyaW5nLTEKU3RyaW5nLTI=" - LF (Linux) Destination character set. The second line does not work "U3RyaW5nLTENClN0cmluZy0y" - CRLF (Windows) Destination character set. I can specify this when encoding the text. For a pdf file I do not know how to do. Tried in Cygwin64 does not work. @David Carlisle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works if you do it this way:

```
\directlua{%
 local file = io.open("base64.txt", "wb");
 file:write((mime.unb64("U3RyaW5nLTENClN0cmluZy0y")));
 file:close();
}
```